# Keep track of caches in neural net

Tags: python, neural-network

I tried to implement a L-layer neural net model, based on Coursera deep learning course, but have a problem with adding cache into caches list.

```
caches = list.append(cache)
```

The course suggests using list.append() function. The rest of codes are as below:

```
def L_model_forward(X, parameters):
    """
    Implement forward propagation 

    Arguments:
    X -- data, numpy array of shape (input size, number of examples)
    parameters -- output of initialize_parameters_deep()

    Returns:
    AL -- last post-activation value
    caches -- list of caches containing:
                every cache of linear_activation_forward() (there are L-1 of them, indexed from 0 to L-1)
    """

    caches = []
    A = X
    L = len(parameters) // 2   # number of layers in the neural network

    # Implement [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1). Add "cache" to the "caches" list.
    for l in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A 
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
        A, cache = linear_activation_forward(A_prev, parameters['W' + str(l)], parameters['b' + str(l)], activation = "relu")
        caches = list.append(cache)
        ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Implement LINEAR -> SIGMOID. Add "cache" to the "caches" list.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    AL, cache =  linear_activation_forward(A, parameters['W' + str(L)], parameters['b' + str(L)], activation = "sigmoid")
    caches = list.append(cache)    
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(AL.shape == (1,X.shape[1]))

    return AL, caches
```

When I run the codes, **here is the error**:

---

> TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a
>   'tuple'

Comment: change type of cache from tuple to list first and then append in caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append in list using `caches = list.append(cache)`. It has to be appended by `caches.append(cache)` and also, before appending in `caches` convert tuple cache into list using `cache=list(cache)` and then append in caches list using `caches.append(cache)`.

You code will look like:-

```
def L_model_forward(X, parameters):

    caches = []
    A = X
    L = len(parameters) // 2   # number of layers in the neural network
    for l in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A 

        A, cache = linear_activation_forward(A_prev, parameters['W' + str(l)], parameters['b' + str(l)], activation = "relu")
        caches.append(list(cache))


    AL, cache =  linear_activation_forward(A, parameters['W' + str(L)], parameters['b' + str(L)], activation = "sigmoid")
    caches.append(list(cache))    

    assert(AL.shape == (1,X.shape[1]))

    return AL, caches
```